# Find a branch in Json hierarchy containing a value

Tags: scala, circe

I have a service that responds with a JSON multi-level hierarchy and I need to parse it and extract a single branch that contains a node with a specific attribute value.

Consider the following JSON hierarchy example reponse:

```
{
  "sku": "ROOT"
  "children": [
   {"sku": "MIDCHILD1", 
     "children": [{"sku": "CHILD1"}, {"sku": "CHILD2"}]},
   {"sku": "MIDCHILD2", 
     "children": [{"sku": "CHILD3", {"sku": "CHILD4"}}]}
  ]
}
```

I need to implement a function using Scala using Circe to extract a branch, providing it receives an `sku` value that might be found at any level of the hierarchy.

examples of expected results:

- Funding by sku ROOT should extract [ROOT,MIDCHILD1,CHILD1,CHILD2,MIDCHILD2,CHILD3,CHILD4]
- Finding by sku MIDCHILD1 should extract [ROOT,MIDCHILD1,CHILD1,CHILD2]
- Finding by sku CHILD2 should extract [ROOT, MIDCHILD1, CHILD2]

Does someone know an easy way to achieve this with Circe?